# Angular subscribe to EventEmitter but fetch existing items

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, angular-components, eventemitter

I'm trying to build a notification component. For that I need to send notifications to `NotificationComponent` through service. My way of doing that is to send notifications to component by using EventEmitter but I want `NotificationComponent` to fetch existing notifications when it is first time routed to by subscribing to Observable of Notifications but it is not working. Looking at my code, please point out problem or suggest alternative way.

At present it only displays notification from notification number 2(That mean first notification does not arrive to `NotificationComponent` but 2 and so on arrive)

**Following is the code of NotificationService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Notification } from './notification';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
  private notifications = [];
  addEvent = new EventEmitter();
  removeEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  add(title: string, message: string, expiresInSeconds: number = null) {
    const noti = new Notification();
    noti.title = title;
    noti.message = message;
    this.notifications.push();

    this.addEvent.emit(noti);
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {notification: 'notification'}}]);

    if (expiresInSeconds > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.removeById(noti.id);
      }, expiresInSeconds * 1000);
    }
  }

  /* get notifications */
  getNotifications() {
    return from(this.notifications);
  }

  /* remove a notification */
  removeById(notificationId) {
    const index = this.notifications.findIndex(n => {
      return notificationId === n.id;
    });
    this.notifications.splice(index, 1);

    this.removeEvent.emit(notificationId);
  }

}
```

**Following is the code of NotificationComponent class**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from '../notification.service';
import { Notification } from '../notification';
import { faWindowClose } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notifications',
  templateUrl: './notifications.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notifications.component.scss']
})
export class NotificationsComponent implements OnInit {
  notifications: Notification[] = [];
  faWindowClose = faWindowClose;

  constructor(private ns: NotificationService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ns.getNotifications()
      .subscribe(notifications => {
      this.notifications = notifications;
    });

    this.ns.addEvent
      .subscribe((notification => {
        this.notifications.push(notification);
      }));

    this.ns.removeEvent
      .subscribe((notification => {
        const index = this.notifications.findIndex(n => {
          return n.id === notification.id;
        });
        this.notifications.splice(index, 1);
      }));
  }

  removeNotification(id) {
    this.ns.removeById(id);

    if (this.notifications.length <= 0) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/user-panel');
    }
  }
}
```

**Following is the template html of NotificationComponent**

```html
<div *ngIf="notifications.length >= 1"
  class="notification d-flex flex-row-reverse p-0">
  <div *ngFor="let n of notifications"
    class="alert alert-dark mx-1 p-0">

    <div class="d-flex flex-row p-0">
      <div class="flex-item flex-grow-1">
        <h5>{{n.title}}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
          (click)="removeNotification(n.id)">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faWindowClose"></fa-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>{{n.message}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your .html

Comment: Don't use EventEmitter for anything other than component outputs. Use a Subject or one of its variants (BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject).

Comment: @ChanakaWeerasinghe HTML added, please review

Comment: am I right that `NotificationsComponent` is rendered by Angular router?

Comment: @Andrei Yeah NotificationComponent is in secondary outlet, I navigate to it whenever a new Notification is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert addEvent to ReplaySubject. Your component renders after the first notification is emitted and subscribes to events only after the first event is gone. With ReplaySubject your component should get that first event.

```
addEvent = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

also it seems there is a small bug

```
this.notifications.push();
```

no notification is pushed to the array and will cause error when calling `removeById`